# Do Germanium BJTs have lower impedance than Silicon BJTs?

Tags: transistors, bjt, impedance

What brings this up is the fact that Germanium has a higher electron mobility than Silicon(as well as lower barrier potential) and does that translate to greater admittance(including susceptance)?